# Use Linq to get items in a list using a second list

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I've been struggling with this for a couple of hours and would appreciate some help/advice if possible.

I have a list of ID's - List()
I have a list of products - List()

I want to pull all rows from the product list where an ID exists.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Read about LINQ `Join` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use contains

```
var items = products.Where(p => idList.Contains(p.ID));
```

Comment: Seems I was very close - I'm sure I had this identical syntax at one stage - but obviously not! Thanks this works.

Answer (score 1):

You need something like this?

```
List<Product> products = // initialize list
List<int>     IDs =      // initialize list

List<Product> containedProducts = products.Where(p => IDs.Contains(p.ID)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = from p in products
             join i in ids
             on p.Id = i
             select p;
```